# SQL Join Four Tables

Tags: sql, join, select, disambiguation

I am trying to join 4 tables using sql. The tables are "Article" (Primary key "a_id", "title", "au_id", "i_id"), "Author" (Primary key "au_id", "name"), "Issue" (Primary key "i_id", "j_id", "number"), "Journal" (Primary key "j_id", "title").

I've tried INNER JOINS, JOIN with WHERE, disambiguing. Currently running code (in one line):

```
const sql = "SELECT a_id, Journal.title, Article.Title, Issue.Number, Author.Name 
FROM Article AS a 
INNER JOIN Author AS au ON a.au_id = au.au_id 
INNER JOIN Issue AS iss ON a.i_id = iss.i_id 
INNER JOIN Journal AS j ON iss.j_id = j.j_id";
```

I keep getting "no such column" when columns exists and have also been trying WC3 examples and tutorials without success.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: Use the table aliases in the SELECT list too.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `FROM Article AS a` so `Article.Title` does not exist. Use `a.Title` instead. Same is true for the other table aliases you have used

Comment: Hi and thank you for your replies. I am now running  const sql = "SELECT a.a_id, j.title, a.title, iss.number, au.name 
 FROM Article AS a 
 INNER JOIN Author AS au ON a.au_id = au.au_id 
 INNER JOIN Issue AS iss ON a.i_id = iss.i_id 
 INNER JOIN Journal AS j ON iss.j_id = j.j_id";.     However it only display the issue and authors.  The article title and journal still does not display in the rows

Comment: @OmarAsamed That's a different question. Please accept this answer, and ask a new question.

Comment: Certainly am grateful and accept